# regex to match string content until comment

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to match to expresions contained within `[%___%]` in a string, before `//` (comments)  excluding `//` that are in quotations (inside a string)
so for example
`[%tag%] = "a" + "//" + [%tag2%]; //[%tag3%]`
should match `[%tag%]` and `[%tag2%]`

The closest I can get is `^(?:(?:\[%([^%\]\[]*)%\])|[^"]|"[^"]*")*?(?://)`

So the problems I'm having are that this doesn't match any strings which don't end in `//`
In fact, it aggregates lines until it can conclude in one that contains `//`
I've tried to remedy this problem with `?.*?$` at the end, to signify that `//` is not necessary and to go to the first endline, but it doesn't really work.

And Secondly, it only captures the second tag. This isn't because of the `"//"` since even with `[%1%] [%2%]` it won't capture the first

I'm using C# and `Regex.Matches` with the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option and this is my escaped string

```
"^(?:(?:\\[%([^%\\]\\[]*)%\\])|[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*?(?://)"
```

Comment: Are you writing a compiler with regex?

Comment: I'm validating a user provided script before sending it off to a calculation engine[:(]. I have to ensure that each tag matches an existing variable, so this is my way of extracting them. It probably would have saved time to just use a loop and substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think doing this in one shot is a little difficult because of double quotes matching being difficult to check. You can do it in two phases:

¤ Removing all matching double quotes
¤ Finding your pattern

```
Regex re1 = new Regex(@"""[^""]*""", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Regex re2 = new Regex(@"(?<!//.*)\[%\w+%\]", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string input = @"[%tag%] = ""a"" + ""//"" + [%tag2%]; //[%tag3%]
[%tag%] = ""a"" + ""ii//"" + [%tag2%]; //[%tag3%]";

MatchCollection ms = re2.Matches(re1.Replace(input, ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, let me just say that I love regexes. I read [Friedl's Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) years ago and never looked back. That being said, do **not** use one giant regex to solve this problem. Use your programming language. You'll end up with more readable and maintainable code. It looks like you're trying to parse a language here where different rules apply in different contexts. Your pattern could appear in a quoted string. Quoted strings might have quotes inside them which need to be escaped. Capturing all the subtleties in one regex would be a nightmare. I recommend iterating through the string character by character, building tokens along the way, looking for the quotes, and keeping track of whether or not you're in a quoted string. When you encounter a token that matches your criteria (you can use a regex for this part), and you're not within a string, add it to your list. When you hit the end of a statement and encounter the beginning of a comment, discard the remaining characters until the end of the comment.